# Will_Paginate::Collection missing the total_entries property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am creating a `Will_Paginate::Collection` object using the following code

```
@paginatedResults = WillPaginate::Collection.new(1, 5)
@paginatedResults.replace @results[@paginatedResults.offset, 
                                   @paginatedResults.per_page]
```

but when I try to render the pagination using

```
<%= will_paginate @paginatedResults %>
```

I get an exception

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.>
```

I have traced it back to the `total_entries` property on the `Will_Paginate::Collections` object. The property is missing. I don't know why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the count manually if you use new to create it, from the API docs:

> new  (page, per_page, total = nil)
>
> Arguments to the constructor are the current page number, per-page limit and the total number of entries. The last argument is optional because it is best to do lazy counting; in other words, count conditionally after populating the collection using the replace method.